# Attempting to condense my c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to condense my c# code because it's way too long and I feel I could use a foreach loop for my code. And you will have to excuse me if my terminology/vocabulary is incorrect, I am a Jr. programmer and still picking up the pieces.

A snippet of my code:

```
if (sender == LinkButtonA)
{
   Session["LastNameFilter"] = "A";
}
if (sender == LinkButtonB)
{
   Session["LastNameFilter"] = "B";
}
if (sender == LinkButtonC)
{
   Session["LastNameFilter"] = "C";
}
if (sender == LinkButtonD)
{
   Session["LastNameFilter"] = "D";
}
```

etc.....

Basically it is changing the filter so that I can display my "patients" in a RadGrid and filter them by their last name. But as you can see, I have to have 26 if statements just to make this work. Is their a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: From the code above it looks like you are always comparing sender to the same value. Is that correct? Is sender always equal to 'LinkButtonA'?

Comment: I assume you have a copy/paste error there, so the second if should read "if (sender == LinkButtonB)", correct?

Comment: My mistake, it corresponds with the Filter.

Comment: What type is the LinkButton? Does it have any field populated (like Id) from which you could extract A, B, C, etc?

Answer (score 4):

You could have a dictionary mapping the buttons to the filters:

```
static Dictionary<Button, string> mapping = new Dictionary<Button, string>() {
    { LinkButtonA, "A" },
    { LinkButtonB, "B" },
    { LinkButtonC, "C" },
    { LinkButtonD, "D" },
};

...

Session["LastNameFilter"] = mapping[sender];
```

Answer (score 1):

Register your buttons in a `Dictionary<Button,string>` :

```
Dictionary<Button,string> lastNameFilterByButton = new Dictionary<Button,string>()`

mapping.Add(LinkButtonA, "A");
mapping.Add(LinkButtonB, "B");
mapping.Add(LinkButtonC, "C");
mapping.Add(LinkButtonD, "D");

// ...    

Session["LastNameFilter"] = lastNameFilterByButton[sender]
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the Tag property on your buttons to the appropriate string, then set the session value to the tag:

```
// in the designer file
LinkButtonA.Tag = "A";
LinkButtonB.Tag = "B";
// etc.

// in the event
var btn = sender as LinkButton;
if (btn != null)
   Session["LastNameFilter"] = (string)btn.Tag;
```

Edit: Tag is found on WinForms controls, ASP controls don't have a direct equivalent. You could probably safely use the CommandArgument property for this, though, if you're not using it for anything else (as pointed out by Jason Nesbitt).

You could also use the name of the button (`Session["LastNameFilter"] = btn.Name.Substring(btn.Name.Length-1, 1);`). This saves you the trouble of messing with the Tags, but means everything breaks if you change your naming convention.

Comment: I don't see that the LinkButton has a Tag property and I've never heard of that.  Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @JasonNesbitt Good catch, I normally use WinForms where all the controls have a Tag property (which just holds any old object you want to put in it to store data with the control), but ASP LinkButton has no such property.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be the case.  Web Forms has a CommandArgument property that somewhat serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
// Is sender of type Control?
Dictionary<Control, string> lookupBasedOnButton = new Dictionary<Control, string>()
{
    { LinkButtonA, "A" },
    // etc
};

Session["LastNameFilter"] = lookupBasedOnButton(sender);
```

Depending on your needs, you might need to add error handling (e.g. check whether the item is in the dictionary, rather than throwing if it is not).

Answer (score 0):

Store and fetch the value from the CommandArgument property of the LinkButton.

```
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButtonA" CommandArgument="A" OnClick="LinkButtonA_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>

    protected void lb LinkButtonA_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lb = (LinkButton) sender;
        Session["LastNameFilter"] = lb.CommandArgument;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add the filter value as a Command Argument to the Button then you only would need to do this (Applies to web forms LinkButton):

```
public void LinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    Session["LastNameFilter"] = linkButton.CommandArgument;
}
```